# Strange behavior with Laravel Sail: after a restart I need to rebuild

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

Strange behavior with Laravel Sail: after a reboot, I need to rebuild with `docker-compose build --no-cache`

I verify that the container is active, and other apps like TablePlus connect perfectly, although it is true that it does so through 127.0.0.1 in its configuration

```bash
Tests\Console\Commands\Tasks\Api\AnalyzerCallsCommandTest::time_and_astro_event_generate_normal_job
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

### my .env.testing

```bash
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3306
```

### my .env

```bash
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sitelight
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
FORWARD_DB_PORT=3306
```

With these settings I can access localhost and log in (use database for this action), access MySQL in Tableplus with server 127.0.0.1

On every change run in sail clear all caches and configs.

### Workaround

I need to use in every down MacBook run a stop docker, and run `sail build --no-cache`

### Edited at 15/Aut/2022

### Workaournd II

After seeing some posts on the internet, y get an ugly solution

```bash
$ docker network inspect bridge
...
"Config": [
    {
        "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
    }
]
```

If edit my .env.testing

```
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1
```

With this workaround works fine.

But after some time (2 o 3 hours of programming and testing) problem persists with **timeout"

```bash
Time: 00:30.131, Memory: 36.50 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Console\Commands\Tasks\Api\AnalyzerCallsCommandTest::just_one_second_before_first_event_for_analyzer_cron_at_sunset_send_normal_job
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

/Users/abkrim/Sites/sitelight/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
```

Of course, at this moment I do some checks:

- On table plus work fine connection to MySQL docker
- On browser any problem with access to MySQL data

Comment: can it be your .env file is no longer present in the php container? You can verify this by opening the console in docker desktop and just `ls` in the directory.

Comment: @onlineThomas On project is .env, .env.testing Y see on console and on PhpStorm

Comment: What is present on the Mac side is not necessarily present in the container.

Comment: I changed method for put configuration in phpunit.xml `<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>` instead using .env.testing and work fine, almost  in last 24 hours of work. Thanks.